# How to expand the bottom of a card on mouse hover? Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have card with image file and text where I want to do hover effect. I just want to display more information of product on mouse hover like image below. Card is overlaying the other card. How can I achieve this? Please help. [image]Flutter Web

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mouse Region to detect a hover and use the animation class for animating the widget. create a separate widget for this box and use it like this. here is a code sample you may like to use.

---

### Sample Code here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

bool touched = false;
String image1 =
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525786210598-d527194d3e9a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80';
String image2 =
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578616070222-50c4de9d5ade?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60';
String image3 =
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502324224542-7ea9927946fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60';

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: const Color(0xff393e46),
          child: Center(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                HoverImage(
                  image: image1,
                ),
                HoverImage(
                  image: image2,
                ),
                HoverImage(
                  image: image3,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HoverImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;

  const HoverImage({required this.image});

  @override
  _HoverImageState createState() => _HoverImageState();
}

class _HoverImageState extends State<HoverImage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation _animation;
  late Animation padding;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 275),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 1.2)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.ease, reverseCurve: Curves.easeIn));
    padding = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: -25.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.ease,reverseCurve: Curves.easeIn));
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _controller.forward();
        });
      },
      onExit: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _controller.reverse();
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 20.0),
              spreadRadius: -10.0,
              blurRadius: 20.0,
            )
          ],
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 220.0,
          width: 170.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          transform: Matrix4(_animation.value, 0, 0, 0, 0, _animation.value, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 1, 0, padding.value, padding.value, 0, 1),
          child: Image.network(
            widget.image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide me how to overlap grid item?

Comment: You can use overflowbox widget for that.

Comment: you can also use Transform.scale